# How to get WiFi IP of connected iOS device from the shell?

Tags: ios, bash, shell, wifi

With a iOS device connected (through USB) to a Mac, how can I get it WiFi IP from the shell?

I've tried `iosdeviceinfo` – an utility from [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) – which returns many informations regarding the connected device, including its WiFi Address. But instead of returning the IP, it returns the MAC Address.

Is there any way to return de IP of the device?

Comment: I'd `arp -a | grep 28:27:9:e2:3:54` once I connected my Mac to the same WiFi as the iOS device, but perhaps you don't really want the IP address but want to learn how USB can get info from iOS? What problem are you actually chasing here?

Comment: You can use ideviceinfo -k WiFiAddress to get the WifiMACAddress first (28:27:9:e2:3:54) and then use arp -na| grep as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm worried that its not possible to do, unless there are some special apple utilities which are exposing all the information to hosting Mac system.

Basically it depends on your setup, are you using the shared internet from iPhone ? Then you might check it somewhere on your "router"s level.

From the other point just imagine in your case the iPhone as a standalone pc connected via USB to your hosting pc. So this standalone pc should theoretically not expose any internal information due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can derive the information from the aarp tables but that requires the machine and device to have talked to each other recently since this is a network cache.